# putObject() times out on files larger than ~1MB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

When trying to upload a CSV file to my S3 bucket using the `putObject()` function, it will timeout if the file is larger than about 1 MB. The largest CSV file I've been able to successfully upload is 1048 KB (25500 lines), and it was only successful four of the 6 times I tried uploading it. Any file smaller than 1 MB though uploads very quickly without any failure. What would cause the function to get hung up and time out once it reaches the ~1 MB threshold?

Relevant code is below:

```js
function writeToS3(){
    var params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Body: fs.createReadStream(fileName)
    }
      
    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log('Error uploading data to S3 bucket: ' + err);
            throw err;
        } else{
            console.log("Data uploaded to S3 bucket: ", util.inspect(data));
        }
    });
}
```

Below is the error message:

```
 Error uploading data to S3 bucket: TimeoutError: Connection timed out after 120000ms
    C:\Users\426782\documents\workspace-sts\lf-rti-file-copier-sql\node_modules\aws-sdk-proxy\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:31
                throw err;
                ^

    TimeoutError: Connection timed out after 120000ms
        at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\426782\documents\workspace-sts\lf-rti-file-copier-sql\node_modules\aws-sdk-proxy\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\http\node.js:83:34)
        at ClientRequest.g (events.js:292:16)
        at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:185:7)
        at Socket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:630:10)
        at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
        at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
        at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:338:8)
        at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)

    npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test" "65056"
    npm ERR! node v6.11.4
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! lf-rti-file-copier@1.0.0 test: `serverless invoke local -f dataRefresh -s dev -d  "65056"`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the lf-rti-file-copier@1.0.0 test script 'serverless invoke local -f dataRefresh -s dev -d  "65056"'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the lf-rti-file-copier package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     serverless invoke local -f dataRefresh -s dev -d  "65056"
    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs lf-rti-file-copier
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls lf-rti-file-copier
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: *"it will timeout"* ... what exactly is timing out?  What error is being thrown?

Comment: Hi @Michael, I've updated the question with the error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and I suggest you try this method `upload.`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property

> Uploads an arbitrarily sized buffer, blob, or stream, using
>   intelligent concurrent handling of parts if the payload is large
>   enough.

Here is an example how your code can be transformed:

```
function writeToS3() {
  fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', function (err, contents) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error during reading file: ' + err);
      throw err;
    } else {
      // Create a binary data from stream
      var base64data = Buffer.from(contents, 'binary')

      var params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Body: base64data
      }

      s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error uploading data to S3 bucket: ' + err);
          throw err;
        } else {
          console.log("Data uploaded to S3 bucket: ", util.inspect(data));
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Also, please, take a look at `Bluebird` library [method](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html), this will help you to transform all methods into promises so that it will be more readable.

**CHANGE TIMEOUT**

There is a place in Lambda dashboard where you can change `Timeout`
Here is a screenshot of it. Please change it to 5 minutes.
[image: Basic settings]

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, unfortunately it still seems to time out on larger files

Comment: I guess, I have another solution, I will update the answer. Please, take a look at *CHANGE TIMEOUT*